# How can I programmatically add entries to Bash history and have timestamps work properly?

Tags: bash, command-history

On CentOS 6.2 and Bash 4.1.2(1), I have added a file in `/etc/profile.d` which contains:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%c : '
history -s "# some text as a marker"
```

That works insofar as the the variable gets set and the marker is written to the user's history list (and to `~/.bash_history` when they `exit`).

The problems are:

- `history -s` doesn't add a timestamp when it adds the marker
- scrolling back through history stops at the marker (the `~/.bash_history` file isn't read into memory)
- the history entry for the marker comment has "??" instead of the (missing) timestamp

I tried adding:

```
history -s "#$(date +%s)"
```

before the other `history -s` command, but Bash sees this as a command in history rather than a timestamp even though it's in the same format.

Another option is to append the marker and a timestamp directly to `~/.bash_history`, but then they are not contiguous with the activity in the session's history when it later gets appended. There may be other sessions that get appended between the marker and its related session due to other users or multiple sessions by a single user.

Is there any way to solve these problems?

**Update:**

I have tried adding `set -o history` (and removed the `history -s "#$(date +%s)"` line) and it seems to solve the history scrolling problem mentioned above, but the lack of timestamp is still a problem.

Comment: `eval history -s "#$(date +%s)"` ?? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this question on the [help-bash mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2012-06/msg00021.html) and got a response from Chet Ramey, the maintainer of [Bash](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashtop.html).

He suggested adding either of the following before the `history -s` command:

```
set -H    # aka set -o histexpand
```

or

```
histchars='!^#'
```

I tried each of them and they both work. The reason is that the history comment character which defaults to `#` hasn't been set at the point that the profile code is running and so is null (`\0`).

Here's my working file:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%c : '
histchars='!^#'
set -o history
history -s "# some text as a marker"
```

Comment: Saw your mail first. Think I might do that, (add a marker)... it's a good idea.

Comment: This did not work for me (Bash 4.1.5), neither `-H`, `histchars` nor `set -o history`. To the contrary, **all** lines of my `.bashrc` are added that are followed by `set -o history` even though `history` is on by default. I consider this a bug.
However, I used it for a workaround: I put `histchars='!^#'`, followed by `set -o history` and `history -s "# some text as a marker"` at the very end of `.bashrc`. This adds indeed the marker and does not delete the history.

Comment: The reason for the delay is basically to give the RC file time to set history options,
before BASH actually reads the history file.